# Is there a working online random adventure generator for D&D 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tools, tool-recommendation, generator

I'm looking for a random adventure/encounter generator for D&D 3.5e. It doesn't have to be particularly good or fleshed out, I intend to use it to generate ideas for one-off side- adventures - ideally it will let me spam a few adventure ideas in a short time, until one feeds my inspiration.

Comment: http://www.asmor.com/scripts.php Has quite a few 4e resources. That, combined with the adventure seed http://www.asmor.com/scripts/pulpscigen/seedgen.php should be able to give you a monster theme and seed name. But, as this is 4e, I don't feel it should be an answer.

Comment: Voting to close this as duplicate of the newer one. Not usually what I'd do, but considering we're making online tool recommendations, more recent is probably = more reliable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I Think [this donjon page](http://donjon.bin.sh/d20/random/#quest) would work for what you want, and if it doesn't, then one of the other generators on the site might.

Comment: donjon's my favorite resource for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 4):

### [Abulafia](http://www.random-generator.com)

Abulafia is a special kind of wiki - it's built to support the creation and use of random generators.

So, if one of the generators on [this page](http://www.random-generator.com/index.php?title=Plot_Kickers_and_Oracles) - like the [Fantasy Adventure Generator](http://www.random-generator.com/index.php?title=Fantasy_Adventure_Generator) or the [Fantasy Scenario Generator](http://www.random-generator.com/index.php?title=Fantasy_Scenario_Generator) - doesn't do what you want, you can start crafting the generator that **does** do what you want. And because it, like StackExchange, is community-driven, you'll be helping others and maybe getting some contributions while you're at it.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple good ones:

- http://www.monsteradvancer.com/ (also has other generators)
- http://www.dmtools.org/encounters.php
- http://www.sulerin.com/creatures/ (try dropping the creatures part if that doesn't work)

For my purposes they didn't use enough resources I have something like 300 pdf resources and wanted to generate something that had roughly 25-40 creatures per table based off of % rolls without having to look through every single book I have for a campaign that is supposed to go up to around level 26-28, and I need to generate an entire world's encounters as I am trying to create a custom campaign setting for all of my campaigns.  In all likelihood I will probably use one of the three I mentioned, I don't play in 4e so if anyone has an idea where I could generate the kind of table that I mentioned I would be grateful.